# Implementing validation for Texboxes in Item Templates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I think it is all bout manually trigerring validation for data template.

For example I have my checklistbox (it is from Xceed wpf extended toolkit, but it doesnt matter. It can be a simple listbox for the sake of example):

```
    <xctk:CheckListBox Name="myCheckListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" Margin="10,10,10,72">
        <xctk:CheckListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding Field.Symbol}"/>
                    <Label Content="Value:" Visibility="{Binding SelectedValueVisibility}"/>
                    <TextBox Name="myTextBox" Width="100" Visibility="{Binding SelectedValueAppVisibility}" 
                    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}" >
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="TextValue" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <my:EmptyTextValidator></my:EmptyTextValidator>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </xctk:CheckListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </xctk:CheckListBox>
```

I have my EmptyTextValidator class similiar to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation

For clarification: "Value: {TextBox}" appears only when an item is checked. 
The problem is the same as if it was a simple Listbox and all the textboxes would be visible from the beginning.

**What is needed:**
Show validation errors on Button_click.

**The problem:**
Validation works only after you enter something.
When user loads my control and instantly clicks "OK", validation errors are not displayed.

To trigger validation manually I need a "static" textbox:

```
textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

I am unable to do it with a texbox in template.
This is also the reason why I am unable to do it throught e.g IDataErrorInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in the class where the `TextValue` property is defined and raise the `ErrorsChanged` event whenever you want to invalidate the `TextBox`. Please refer to the following TechNet article for a sample implementation: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx.

So in your `Button` click event handler, or in your command, you could iterate through the items in your `Fields` collection and call a method or something of each of these objects that performs the validation and raises the `ErrorsChanged`. This should cause the `Validation.Error` template of the invalid `TextBox` elements in the `ListView` to be displayed as expected.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because the idea is great and I will use it in the future, this was exactly what I was looking. However the aplication I am working on uses .net 3.5... I quess I am stuck with good old style triggers to do some validation on empty Texboxes... :/